# How do i draw a UIView to a CGContext without renderInContext when it is not attached to any hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am drawing stuff onto a video frame and the best way i found is to get the `CVImageBufferRef` from the Video frame and then draw into/onto it like with any other CGContext drawing.

Now i have loads of UIViews that i simply create without adding them to any superview. I want these UIViews drawn without renderInContext because this would take me 1 second per frame or 30 sec rendertime per second of video.

If i use `drawViewHierarchyInRect` nothing is drawn.

If i use `drawRect` nothing is drawn and i get lots of invalid context errors

I am calling `setNeedsDisplay`and `setNeedsLayout` before and the Rects are all valid.

Same issue with non-custom UIViews like a UILabel.

```
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

   // Lock the image buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);



    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer),
                                                     CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer),
                                                     CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer),
                                                     8,
                                                     CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer),
                                                     colorSpace,
                                                     kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little |
                                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);


    // now i want to draw my UIView


    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);



    // Unlock the image buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the UIViews are not added to any superviews, there is nowhere to draw to. Fundamentally, drawing only happens on the device screen (except for rendering specifically to specially created contexts like pdf or image contexts or a bitmap context like the one you created).

When you normally draw to a UIView, it is part of a hierarchy that ultimately is part of a single graphics context that maps all drawing to the devices screen.

You can draw into the bitmap context you created using CG calls. If you are trying to draw text you may need to use CoreText.

Comment: i have about 20 very complex UIViews that i need to draw onto a video frame. So how would i do that ?

Comment: The only "trick" I can think of is for you to create a UIView and place it behind everything else in your main view hierarchy. Attach your complex views to that, and render its layer into a bitmap context.