# How can i draw a NSString onto a custom non-visible CGContext?

Tags: ios, nsstring, cgcontext, avassetwriter

following to my question: [How do i draw a UIView to a CGContext without renderInContext when it is not attached to any hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127758/how-do-i-draw-a-uiview-to-a-cgcontext-without-renderincontext-when-it-is-not-att)

My goal is to draw stuff on a video, frame by frame.
So i get the video frames and create a context with `CGBitmapContextCreate`

If i use `NSString drawAtPoint:`nothing is visible.
Somewhere on SO someone suggested to use
`UIGraphicsPushContext(context);`

`// now draw the string`

`UIGraphicsPopContext();`

If i do that, the text is visible on the video however the AssetWriterInput seems to hang itself after about 40 frames.
`writerInputVideo.readyForMoreMediaData == NO`will always be true (i am checking in a loop with sleep cycles) and thus stuck.

The video will obviously be longer than 40 frames and i dont know why it hangs in the first place but i need to draw lots of texts and the only other option i found was to create bitmaps of letters and create my text out of bitmaps but that would be too much work. There has to be some way to draw strings on a context without all this trouble ?!